# GSON unable to serialize exception with Java 17

Tags: java, gson

The following code used to work on Java 11:

```
new Gson().toJson(new Exception())
```

On JDK 17 I get the following error:

```
Unable to make field private java.lang.String java.lang.Throwable.detailMessage accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @147ed70f
```

From reading [this page](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1875), I think I could resolve it with `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED`. Is there a better way however? Perhaps with a custom de/serializer?

Comment: Why are you serializing a class whose structure can merely change from version to version or can be different between different JDK/JRE implementations breaking your design completely? You have no control over it at all. Gson, by design, uses reflection for objects it is not aware of (no special type adapters registered), thus it simply iterates through all object fields regardless they are public or private. Private stuff of a foreign library is never meant to be serialized like this. Never.

Comment: We have two services. When A calls B, B can throw an exception. I serialize it and pass it back to A, so A can include it as the cause of the exception it throws. It's useful for investigating crashes; I didn't realise this was such a no-no.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the purpose, but you need your own data transfer objects (DTO) to carry the exceptions data, so that your DTOs are fully controlled by you and you decide what data should be taken from exceptions that may have more private fields than I even think of (private fields, package-private or private classes, various references or circular references, etc). It will require some code to map from exes to DTOs (and then back to exes if necessary), but then you will never run into such issues using only public API of `Throwable`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I added to de/serialize exceptions. This can be used in a class like this:

```
public class Result {
    public final Object result;
    public final Error error;

    public Result(Object result) { ... }

    public Result(Exception e) {
        this.result = null;
        this.error = new Error(e);
    }
}
```

And the on the other, call `result.error.toThrowable()`.

```
public static class Error {
    public final String message;
    public final List<STE> stackTrace;
    public final Error cause;

    public Error(Throwable e) {
        message = e.getMessage();
        stackTrace = Arrays.stream(e.getStackTrace()).map(STE::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        cause = e.getCause() != null ? new Error(e.getCause()) : null;
    }

    public Throwable toThrowable() {
        Throwable t = new Throwable(message);
        t.setStackTrace(stackTrace.stream().map(STE::toStackTraceElement).toArray(StackTraceElement[]::new));
        if (cause != null) {
            t.initCause(cause.toThrowable());
        }
        return t;
    }

    private static class STE {
        public final String declaringClass;
        public final String methodName;
        public final String fileName;
        public final int    lineNumber;

        public STE(StackTraceElement ste) {
            this.declaringClass = ste.getClassName();
            this.methodName = ste.getMethodName();
            this.fileName = ste.getFileName();
            this.lineNumber = ste.getLineNumber();
        }

        public StackTraceElement toStackTraceElement() {
            return new StackTraceElement(declaringClass, methodName, fileName, lineNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this yesterday. I was using Java 17. I went back to Java 11 and it worked fine.

I think it's because of this: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8256358

I am lazy and using the GSON default reflection type adapter.

You have to implement your own TypeAdapter to fix it. Or perhaps use another JSON deserializer like Jackson, which I might do later.

Answer (score -3):

Try with the latest release.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson

Comment: that didn't help with the issue